# Passing data between two unrelated screens in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have the following *FiltersScreen* which contains 2 filters and a save button. When a user toggles the filter and clicks on save button, I would like to pass these values to the *CategoryMealsScreen*. How can I pass these values? There is no navigation between these two screens so I can't use push or pushNamed route.

Here are the two classes:

```
class FiltersScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FilterScreenState createState() => _FilterScreenState();
}

class _FilterScreenState extends State<FiltersScreen> {
  var _glutenFree = false;  
   var _lactoseFree = false; 

  Widget _buildSwitchListTile(String title, String subTitle, bool currentValue, Function updateValue){ 
       return  SwitchListTile(title:Text(title), 
                    value:currentValue, 
                    subtitle: Text(subTitle),
                    onChanged: updateValue
                    );
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Filter'), 
        actions:<Widget>[
          IconButton(icon:Icon(Icons.save), onPressed: () {  },),
        ],
        ),
        
        drawer: MainDrawer(),
        body:  Column(children:<Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child:Text('Adjust your meal selection', 
            style:Theme.of(context).textTheme.title), ), 
            Expanded(
              child:ListView(
                children:<Widget>[
                  _buildSwitchListTile('Gluten-free',
                  'Only include gluten free meals',
                   _glutenFree, 
                  (newValue){setState((){ 
                      _glutenFree = newValue; 
                   },); 
                  }),
                  _buildSwitchListTile('Lactose',
                  'Only include lactose free meals',
                   _lactoseFree, 
                  (newValue){setState((){ 
                      _lactoseFree = newValue; 
                   },);  
                  })]
              )
            )
        ]));
  }
}
```

**Here's the class which is supposed to receive the values:**

```
    class CategoryMealsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String categoryId;
  final String categoryTitle;

  CategoryMealsScreen(this.categoryId, this.categoryTitle);

  @override
  _CategoryMealsScreenState createState() => _CategoryMealsScreenState();
}

class _CategoryMealsScreenState extends State<CategoryMealsScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final categoryMeals = DUMMY_MEALS.where((meal) {
      return meal.categories.contains(widget.categoryId);
    }).toList();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(widget.categoryTitle)),
     body: ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
          return MealItem(
            id:categoryMeals[index].id,
            title: categoryMeals[index].title,
            imageUrl: categoryMeals[index].imageUrl,
            duration: categoryMeals[index].duration,
            affordability: categoryMeals[index].affordability,
            complexity: categoryMeals[index].complexity,
          );
        },
        itemCount: categoryMeals.length,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**EDITED**

In the `CategoryMealsScreen`, how can I use both `_glutenFree` and `_lactoseFree` values?

Here's my updated code:

**CategoryMealsScreen**

```
 class CategoryMealsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String categoryId;
  final String categoryTitle;

  CategoryMealsScreen(this.categoryId, this.categoryTitle);

  @override
  _CategoryMealsScreenState createState() => _CategoryMealsScreenState();
}

    class _CategoryMealsScreenState extends State<CategoryMealsScreen> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        ValueListenable<bool> _glutenFree;
        ValueListenable<bool> _lactoseFree;
    
        return ValueListenableBuilder(
            valueListenable: _glutenFree,
            builder: (context, value, _) {
              final categoryMeals = DUMMY_MEALS.where((meal) {
                if (_glutenFree.value && !meal.isGlutenFree) {
                  return false;
                }
                if (_lactoseFree.value && !meal.isLactoseFree) {
                  return false;
                }
                return true;
              }).toList();
    
              //Every independent screen must have a scaffold
              return Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(title: Text(widget.categoryTitle)),
                body: ListView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
                    return MealItem(
                      id: categoryMeals[index].id,
                      title: categoryMeals[index].title,
                      imageUrl: categoryMeals[index].imageUrl,
                      duration: categoryMeals[index].duration,
                      affordability: categoryMeals[index].affordability,
                      complexity: categoryMeals[index].complexity,
                    );
                  },
                  itemCount: categoryMeals.length,
                ),
              );
            });
      }
    }
```

**FiltersScreen**

```
class FiltersScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FilterScreenState createState() => _FilterScreenState();
}

class _FilterScreenState extends State<FiltersScreen> {

ValueNotifier<bool> _glutenFree = new ValueNotifier(false);
ValueNotifier<bool> _lactoseFree = new ValueNotifier(false);

  Widget _buildSwitchListTile(String title, String subTitle, ValueNotifier<bool> currentValue, Function updateValue){ 
       return  SwitchListTile(title:Text(title), 
                    value:currentValue.value, 
                    subtitle: Text(subTitle),
                    onChanged: updateValue
                    );
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Filter'), 
        actions:<Widget>[
          IconButton(icon:Icon(Icons.save), onPressed: () {  },),
        ],
        ),
        
        drawer: MainDrawer(),
        body:  Column(children:<Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child:Text('Adjust your meal selection', 
            style:Theme.of(context).textTheme.title), ), 
            Expanded(
              child:ListView(
                children:<Widget>[
                  _buildSwitchListTile('Gluten-free',
                  'Only include gluten free meals',
                   _glutenFree, 
                  (newValue){setState((){ 
                      _glutenFree.value = newValue; //setting the value
                     _glutenFree.notifyListeners(); //all the widget who is listening to this value, let them know the change
                   },); 
                  }),
                  _buildSwitchListTile('Lactose',
                  'Only include lactose free meals',
                   _lactoseFree, 
                  (newValue){setState((){ 
                      _lactoseFree = newValue; 
                      _lactoseFree.notifyListeners(); 
                   },); 
                  }),
                  ]
              )
            )
        ]));
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any screen from where both of this class is getting called?

Comment: No, there is no such screen.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve such kind of filter effect by using [ValueNotifier](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s-ZG-jS5QHQ) to hold the changes of the filter class and using a `ValueListenableBuilder` in the Category class to listen to that value change and do the necessary change in the UI.

let's jump to the solution, inside your `FiltersScreen`, replace this code

```
var _glutenFree = false;
var _lactoseFree = false;
```

with `ValueNotifier` kind of object. So it'll look like this

```
ValueNotifier<bool> _glutenFree = new ValueNotifier(false);
ValueNotifier<bool> _lactoseFree = new ValueNotifier(false);
```

Changing the value on click is also pretty similar. So this

```
setState((){
    _glutenFree = newValue; 
 });
```

will change into this

```
setState((){
    _glutenFree.value = newValue; //setting the value
    _glutenFree.notifyListeners(); //all the widget who is listening to this value, let them know the change
 });
```

Now the final step, setting up a widget builder that listen to this value change and rebuild all of it's widget in the tree.

To do that, simply add this as a widget inside your `CategoryMealsScreen`

```
ValueListenableBuilder(
    valueListenable: _glutenFree,
    builder: (context, value, _) {
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you look at my edited question and let me know how can I use both _glutenFree and _lactoseFree values in the CategoryMealsScreen ? Much appreciate your help